# Trying to enable 2 sets of text fields with a button and a check box

Tags: javascript

I am no programmer by any stretch of my imagination. I have tried nearly every code I've seen on here to enable a text box only when a radio button or check box is clicked and the problem I face is although the checkbox succeeds in enabling the text fields, nothing is written to my data table. I get the word 'no' written in some instances.

Can any please help?

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
 <title>Help us improve our services for international businesses</title>
    <script language="javascript" src="http://x.canada.ukti.gov.uk/ats/js/lib.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
var hasFocus = false;
var pass = true;
function atsValidate()
{
 //SET PASS
 hasFocus = false;
 pass = true;
 
 //HIDE ERROR ROWS
 hideRow("email"); //Email
 hideRow("what_did_you_want_to_do"); //What did you want to do
 hideRow("please_tell_us_what_specific"); //Please tell us what specific
 hideRow("what_is_the_status"); //What is the status
 hideRow("would_you_be_interested"); //Would you be interested
 hideRow("how_useful_did_you_find_this"); //how useful did you find this
 hideRow("what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service"); //What could we do to improve this service
 hideRow("what_information"); //What information
 
 //VALIDATE SIMPLE FIELDS
 validateText("email"); //Email
 validateText("what_did_you_want_to_do"); //What did you want to do
 validateText("please_tell_us_what_specific"); //Please tell us what specific
 validateText("what_is_the_status"); //What is the status
 validateText("would_you_be_interested"); //Would you be interested
 validateText("how_useful_did_you_find_this"); //how useful did you find this
 validateText("what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service"); //What could we do to improve this service
 validateText("what_information"); //What information
 
 //RETURN SUCCESS OR FAILURE
 return pass;
}
function prefFieldCalc(cb)
{
 // Set Preference field value, Opt-in 100, Opt-out 1500
 if (cb.checked === true){
  document.getElementById(cb.getAttribute("id").replace("cb", "s")).value = 100;
 }
 else{
  document.getElementById(cb.getAttribute("id").replace("cb", "s")).value = 1500;
 }
}
</script>
 <style type="text/css">a:link {
 color: #B00D23;
}

/* Some resets and issue fixes */
        #outlook a { padding:0; }
        body{ width:100% !important; -webkit-text; size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }     
        .ReadMsgBody { width: 100%; }
        .ExternalClass {width:100%;} 
        .backgroundTable {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:100%;!important;} 
        table td {border-collapse: collapse;}
        .ExternalClass * {line-height: 115%;}
  .hero-image {display:block; margin:0 auto;} 
          
        /* End reset */
  
  
  /* These are our tablet/medium screen media queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  
  /* Hero image */
            *[class="hero-image"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;} 
  
  /* Hero image 2 */
            *[class="hero-image2"] {width:100% !important; height:auto !important;}  
 
  /* 100percent width section with 20px padding */
            *[class="container"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px; align-self:center !important;} 
  
  /* Content table with blue background */
            *[class="table-white"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px;} 
 
  /* Content table with blue background */
            *[class="table-blue"] {width:100% !important; padding:20px;}
  
  /* Some more stacking elements */
            *[class="social-button"] {float: none !important; padding:0px 0px 20px 0px;}
   
  /* Some more stacking elements */
            *[class="image_fix"] {float: left !important; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;} 
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#1E1348"><img height="1" src="http://l.email.ukti.gov.uk/rts/open.aspx?tp=i-H8B-Q1q-4Sy-uXpK-2P-1-3E-G-uXpK-fp2ZX" style="display:none" width="1" /><!-- Wrapper/Container Table -->
<table bgcolor="#DFD5C5" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="backgroundTable" width="101%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#1E1348" valign="top"><br />
   <!-- Main Tables -->
   <table align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="container" width="600">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px"><span style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px"><a href="https://invest.great.gov.uk/int/"><img alt="logo-no-flag" class="image_fix" height="39" src="http://wpm.ccmp.eu/wpm/100058/ImageLibrary/images/iigb-logo3.png" width="250" /></a></span></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- KEYLINE -->
     <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px 20px 15px 20px;">
      <hr style="border: 0; height: 0; border-top: 3px solid #B00D23;" /></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- BLUE TABLE BORDER. In we go!! -->
     <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;"><span style="font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif; font-size: 24px; font-style: italic; line-height: 25px; color: #FFFFFF; padding-bottom: 10px;"><a href="https://invest.great.gov.uk/int/"><img alt="Exporting is GREAT" class="hero-image" src="http://wpm.ccmp.eu/wpm/100058/ImageLibrary/images/iigb_alert_image.jpg" style="width: 560px; height: 280px;" /></a></span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><p><span style="font-size: 20px;;">Help us improve our services for international businesses</span>
        
        </p>
        <p>We want to know how we can improve our website to better support your business. 
        
             <br />
             <br />
             Please complete these 7 questions to help us better understand how to help you.</p><form method="post" onSubmit="return atsValidate();" action="go.aspx">
 <input type="hidden" name="cr" value="{(CustomerID)}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="fm" value="{(FormID)}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="sb" value="{(SubmissionID)}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="ri" value="{(PkID)}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="mg" value="{(MessageID)}" />
 <input type="hidden" name="cn" value="{(CampaignID)}" />
 
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td width="29%" align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>Email:</strong></td>
   <td width="71%" align="left"style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><input type="text" id="s_email" name="s_email" value="{(email)}"  required/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_email" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(Email is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top"style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>What did you want to do on great.gov.uk?:</strong></td>
   <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
     <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="s_what_did_you_want_to_do" type="radio" id="s_what_did_you_want_to_do_0" value="I was looking for information because I want to set up or expand my business in a different country to my own" class="radioBtn" /></td>
       <td align="left" valign="top"><label>I was looking for information because I want to set up or expand my business in a different country to my own</label></td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="s_what_did_you_want_to_do" value="I was looking for information about a specific project or business to invest in" id="s_what_did_you_want_to_do_1" class="radioBtn" /></td>
       <td align="left" valign="top">I was looking for information about a specific project or business to invest in</td>
       </tr>
     <tr>
       <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="s_what_did_you_want_to_do" value="Other (please specify)" id="s_what_did_you_want_to_do_2" class="radioBtn"/></td>
       <td align="left" valign="top"><label> Other (please specify) <br />
         </label>
        <textarea name="s_what_did_you_want_to_do" id="s_what_did_you_want_to_do_3" cols="45" rows="5" disabled></textarea>
      <label> </label><script type="text/javascript">
$(".radioBtn").click(function() {
    $("#s_what_did_you_want_to_do_3").attr("disabled", true);
    if ($("input[name=s_what_did_you_want_to_do]:checked").val() == "Other (please specify)") {
        $("#s_what_did_you_want_to_do_3").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
</script></td>
       </tr>
     </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_what_did_you_want_to_do" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(What did you want to do is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>What kind of information were you looking for? (please select all that apply):</strong></td>
    <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
           <tr>
             <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="s_what_information2_" type="checkbox" id="s_what_information2_0" value="Help to set up or expand my business in the UK" checked="checked"></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top"><label>Help to set up or expand my business in the UK</label></td>
              </tr>
           <tr>
             <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="s_what_information2_2" value="Information to help me understand whether the UK would be a good place to set up or expand my business" id="s_what_information2_1"></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top">Information to help me understand whether the UK would be a good place to set up or expand my business</td>
              </tr>
           <tr>
             <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="s_what_information2_3" value="Information to help me find specific projects or businesses to invest in" id="s_what_information2_2"></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top">Information to help me find specific projects or businesses to invest in</td>
              </tr>
           <tr>
             <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="checkbox" name="s_what_information2" value="Other (please specify)" id="s_what_information2_3"></td>
             <td align="left" valign="top">
               <label>Other (please specify)<br>
                 <textarea name="s_what_information" id="s_what_information2" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
               </label></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>
   </tr>
  <tr id="row_what_information2" style="display:none;">
    <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
    <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(What information is required)</span></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>Please tell us what specific details would help you. (For example: business contacts, research reports, etcetera):</strong></td>
   <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><label for="s_please_tell_us_what_specific"></label>
      <textarea name="s_please_tell_us_what_specific2" id="s_please_tell_us_what_specific" cols="45" rows="5" required="required"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_please_tell_us_what_specific" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(Please tell us what specific is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top"style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>What is the status of your current project?:</strong></td>
   <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input name="s_what_is_the_status" type="radio" id="s_what_is_the_status_0" value="We are still planning and have made no decisions" checked="checked"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><label>We are still planning and have made no decisions</label></td>
             </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="s_what_is_the_status" value="We have decided to set up or expand internationally, but not to the UK" id="s_what_is_the_status_1"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top">We have decided to set up or expand internationally, but not to the UK</td>
             </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="s_what_is_the_status" value="We have decided to set up or expand in the UK" id="s_what_is_the_status_2"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><label>We have decided to set up or expand in the UK</label></td>
             </tr>
          <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="s_what_is_the_status" value="We have decided not to expand internationally" id="s_what_is_the_status_3"></td>
            <td align="left" valign="top"><label>
              We have decided not to expand internationally</label></td>
             </tr>
           </table>
         </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_what_is_the_status" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(What is the status is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>The UK government&rsquo;s investment services team can support your business if you are looking to set up in the UK. This is a free service which can help you with market research and building business connections in the UK. Would you be interested in accessing this support?:</strong></td>
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><p>
        <label>
         <input name="s_would_you_be_interested" type="radio" id="s_would_you_be_interested_0" value="Yes" checked="checked">
        Yes</label>
       <br>
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="s_would_you_be_interested" value="No" id="s_would_you_be_interested_1">
         No</label>
       <br>
         </p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_would_you_be_interested" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(Would you be interested is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>Overall, how useful did you find this service?:</strong></td>
   <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><p>
        <label>
         <input name="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this" type="radio" id="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this_0" value="Extremely useful" checked="checked">
        Extremely useful</label>
       <br>
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this" value="Very useful" id="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this_1">
         Very useful</label>
       <br>
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this" value="Somewhat useful " id="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this_2">
         Somewhat useful </label>
       <br>
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this" value="Slightly useful" id="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this_3">
         Slightly useful</label>
       <br>
       <label>
         <input type="radio" name="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this" value="Not at all useful" id="s_how_useful_did_you_find_this_4">
         Not at all useful</label>
       <br>
         </p></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_how_useful_did_you_find_this" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(how useful did you find this is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td align="left" valign="top" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><strong>What could we do to improve this service?:</strong></td>
   <td align="left" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><label for="s_what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service"></label>
      <textarea name="s_what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service2" id="s_what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service" cols="45" rows="5" required="required"></textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row_what_could_we_do_to_improve_this_service" style="display:none;">
   <td align="left" valign="top">&#160;</td>
   <td valign="middle" style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 10px; font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: #000000;"><span class="required">(What could we do to improve this service is required)</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset"></td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</p></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- !New Footer Table -->
     <tr>
      <td style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;"><!-- !Social Media Icons -->
      <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="social-button">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/department-for-international-trade"><img alt="sm-great-link-icon" height="32" src="http://wpm.ccmp.eu/wpm/100058/ImageLibrary/images/socialbuttons/sm-great-link-icon.gif" width="42" /></a></td>
         <td><a href="https://twitter.com/tradegovuk"><img alt="sm-great-tw-icon" height="32" src="http://wpm.ccmp.eu/wpm/100058/ImageLibrary/images/socialbuttons/sm-great-tw-icon.gif" width="43" /></a></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <img alt="HM Government Logo" class="image_fix" src="http://wpm.ccmp.eu/wpm/100058/ImageLibrary/images/HM_Government.png" style="float: left; width: 194px; height: 71px;" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; font-size: 10px; color: #12044B; margin: 0px; line-height: normal; padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;"><a href="https://invest.great.gov.uk" style="font-weight: bold; color: #12044B;">invest.great.gov.uk</a><br />
      <br /></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!-- End example table --></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td bgcolor="#1E1348" style="font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; line-height: 10px; color: #1E1348; padding: 20px; text-align: center"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of wrapper table --></body>
</html>
```

please help?

Comment: It looks like your javascript code is using jQuery functions, but jQuery is not being loaded?

Comment: It's somehow really a lot of markup.. Maybe the best thing todo is to recreate the issue you got in a clean project. Where you just add the elements and code you need. This will help you to create an [mcve]